# R plot logit transformed data on normal axis (logistic transformed)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot logit transformed data (originally percentages) in a comprehensible manner, i.e., in a plot with a logistic transformed y-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

# Logit transformation function
logit <- function(x){
  x <- x/100
  log(x/(1-x))
}

# Create sample data
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,10,1), 
           y = runif(10, 0, 10)) %>% 
  mutate(y = logit(y))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point()
```

I noticed that the `scale_y_continuous` function has a `trans` argument, which should be able to do the job. However, a `logit` function is built-in, but its opposite the `logistic` isn't.

How can I plot logit transformed data normally (i.e., with a logistic transformed y-axis)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is in percentage and you want the y-axis to be logit transformed, with the y axis labels staying as percentage, you can create a new `trans` class from [scales](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/readme/README.html), in the example below, i use qlogis which is the equivalent of your `logit` function:

```
library(scales)
logit_perc <- trans_new("logit perc",
transform = function(x)qlogis(x/100),
inverse = function(x)100*plogis(x)
)

set.seed(1001)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,10,1),y = runif(10, 0, 10)) 

ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + coord_trans(y = logit_perc)
```

[image]

If you have already the values in logit, and you want to plot in logit scale with labels in percentages:

```
df = df %>% mutate(y=logit(y))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x)round(100*plogis(x),digits=1))
```

[image]

while the original plot looks like:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @user213544 if i get you correct, your y-values are in logit, and you want to display them as probability? Thats you mean by interpretable?

Comment: Yes:)! So, for example, the original value was 4.5%. I logit transformed it to -3.055049. But I would like the axis to display the value as 4.5%. So, the transformation should remain present, but the labels should be 'original'.